# Keeping a Java Window always in the back

Tags: java, swing

I wish to keep a java window (JFrame) always in the back, essentially never letting it be in focus or being on top of any other window.

I am currently using this

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        frame.toBack();
    }
});
```

When a window gains focus, it is sent to the back.
It works but there is a delay when a user clicks on the window where the window gets sent to the front then to the back, causing a very noticeable flicker for the user.

Is there any way I can prevent Java or Windows from sending the window to the front at all?

Comment: You can set the window as unfocusable

Comment: frame.setFocusable(false) does not seem to work, the window is still sent to the front for me.

Comment: *"(JFrame) always in the back"* Why? What app. feature does this provide? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: I am trying to simulate a desktop widget and animate a portion of the desktop. Being able to bring that to the front is obnoxious for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one solution I found:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
frame.toBack();
```

It only works if you use setFocusableWindowState(false) and not setFocusable(false)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is, when I open a new Frame I call this method:

```
java.awt.Window[] windows = Window.getWindows();
for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; i++)
{
    windows[i].toFront();
}
```